# Returning "references" and not values from sub?

Tags: perl

I have a sub in perl (generated automatically by SWIG) that I want to return multiple values from.  However, I seem to be getting variable meta-data instead of the actual values.

```
sub getDate {
    my $tm = *libswigperlc::MyClass_getDate;
    ($tm.sec, $tm.min, $tm.hour, $tm.day, $tm.month, $tm.year + 1900);
}
```

The caller is like this...

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$month,$year) = $s->getDate();
print "$year-$month-$day $hour:$min\n";
```

The $tm.year + 1900 *does* return the value as wanted.  If I add "+ 1" to the other values, they work as wanted too.

But

```
print $month;
```

results in

```
*libswigperlc::MyClass_getDatemonth
```

instead of

```
3
```

What is the best way to return the values to the caller?

I am a novice perl user - I use C++ normally.

Comment: Are you saying that things like second and minute are -1 on the hour exactly?

Comment: No - it's not an off-by-one problem.  Instead of getting numerical values back I'm getting meta-data back, like "*libswigperlc::MyClass_getDatemonth" instead of say "3".

Comment: The RHS of your assignment is a typeglob, not a function or a function call.  The expression down below is concatenating barewords, which are probably strings not functions. I can't see any way apart from very heavy tie magic for this to possibly work. But I have never used SWIG, so don't want to be too definite in my denial. I just strongly disbelieve.

Comment: $tm->sec is what you want may be? as tchrist noted, dot is for concatination in Perl

Comment: It certainly works, but only when I put "+ 1" (just like the "+ 1900" shown) next to all the return parameters in the sub.
($tm.sec + 1, $tm.min + 1, $tm.hour + 1, $tm.day + 1, $tm.month + 1, $tm.year + 1900);

Comment: Using -> instead of dot, I get 'Error Can't call method "sec" without a package or object reference at ...'

Comment: Are you getting valid numbers back when using the "+1" trick? Are you using `warnings`?

Comment: It works with the "+ 1" trick, and no warnings.  However, now you mention it, the values I'm getting are either 1 or 1900.  I will try to force a different date value to be presented to the function.  I am "using" strict and warnings.

Comment: By the way... this `libswigperlc::MyClass_getDate`, is that something you wrote yourself?

Comment: Because if we knew what that function returns, we'd solve your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tchrist - you were right to question the typeglob line.  That line was generated by Swig, and I had no understanding of it.

All I had to do was return the typeglob as is...

```
sub getDate { 
    *libswigperlc::MyClass_getDate2; 
}
```

Now the caller can access the members like this...

```
my $tm = myClass->getDate();
print "Year = $tm->{year}";
```

At least now I understand it just well enough to know to leave it as it is, or to change it to be the way as per the original idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go for a longer answer here:

1. First of all, are you using strict and warnings pragmas? (use strict; use warnings;) They will save you a lot of time by taking some of your Perl freedom away (To me, without them you're stepping out from freedom into extreme anarchism (: ).
2. $tm . sec would do this: tries to concatenate $tm with sec. Then what's sec? 
      -If you are using strict pragma, then sec is a sub declared somewhere before the call
      -If you are not using strict pragma (I guess this is the case) sec is used as a bareword.
3. What is *libswigperlc::MyClass_getDate? Is it returning an object that's overloading concatenation operator(.) and/or add operator (+) in it? If yes (and specially without strict/warnings pragmas) you may expect any kind of result depending on the definition of the overload functions. Getting a correct result that you are getting by putting + is one of the possibilities.

That's all that comes to my mind, I hope others add their explanations too or correct mine.

Comment: [not allowed to answer my own question yet]

tchrist - you were right to question the typeglob line.  That line was generated by Swig, and I had no understanding of it.

All I had to do was return the typeglob as is...

    sub getDate { 
        *libswigperlc::MyClass_getDate2; 
    }

Now the caller can access the members like this...

    my $tm = myClass->getDate();
    print "Year = $tm->{year}";

At least now I understand it just well enough to know to leave it as it is, or to change it to be the way as per the original idea.

Thanks all for your help.